# URL-encode parameters in ActionLink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, encode, actionlink

I have the following route registered;

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "LocationsByArea",                                              
            "Locations/{system}/{storage}/{area}",          
            new { controller = "StorageLocation", action = "Index" },
            null
        );
```

...and the following code in my view;

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Platser", "Index", "StorageLocation", new { system = Model.System, storage = Model.Storage, area = item.Name }, null)%>
```

My problem is when the "area = item.Name" contains a colon, e.g. "Area 4:1". If I click the rendered link I get HTTP-error 400, Bad reqest. I guess I have to encode my area parameter in some way, but I cant figure out how. Any help is apreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The built-in encoding/decoding does not work, so I suggest you roll your own, like this:

```
namespace MyProject.Helpers
{
    public static class JobNameHelper
    {
        public static string JobNameEncode(string jobname)
        {
            return jobname.Replace(":", "---colon---");
        }

        public static string JobNameDecode(string jobname)
        {
            return jobname.Replace("---colon---", ":");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use

```
Server.UrlEnconde(item.Name)
```

Or am I missing something?

In your routing you may have to use `Server.UrlDecde` as well although I think It should decode for you on request.

Try using the [Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) to see what the url router is getting passed, then you can see where the decoding needs to happen

Comment: I think you will have to UrlDecode back at the other end when reading it back out.  Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes, I have, but I dont reach into the controller.

Comment: Sounds like the Decoding needs to happen at routing then,  try the routing debugger (I have updated the answer)

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET 3.5 SP1 and earlier have a number of restrictions on which URLs are valid. In ASP.NET 4 most of these issues have been fixes (or are at least customizable via web.config). I think that the colon character, even when encoded, might not be allowed in ASP.NET 3.5 SP1 and earlier due to security concerns. Allowing colons can be a security problem when performing file checks since they are a little-known syntax for [NTFS Alternate Data Streams](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105763).

I recommend trying to choose a character other than a colon for these purposes. Maybe a comma, semi-colon, or equal sign might work instead?